# Microsoft VBScript runtime error Error Description: Object required: 'Server'

Tags: asp-classic, sql-server-2014, windows-server-2012

Am trying to run daily sql job which sends mail to my client using SMTP Server and CDONT Mail objects . Already has the code which works fine for me. Recently i have upgraded the my server from microsoft Server  2003 to 2012 and Sql server 2005 to 2014.

This code below works fine in Classic asp in server. But in sql job getting error

```
Set objEMail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set objConfig = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
Set Confi = objConfig.Fields
Confi("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 1
Confi("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverpickupdirectory") = "C:\inetpub\mailroot\pickup"
Confi.Update
Set objEMail.Configuration = objConfig
objEMail.To = "hi@xx.in"
objEMail.From ="hello@yy.com"
objEMail.Subject = "Email subject goes here"
objEMail.HTMLBody = "Hi Sql job data"
objEMail.Send
Set objEMail = Nothing
```

> Executed as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. Error Code: 0  Error Source= Microsoft VBScript runtime error  Error Description: Object required: 'Server' #

Comment: After the search i have found cdonts.ddl wont support windows hence i tried CDO.

Comment: Can you show us the code that isn't working, rather than the code that is?

Comment: Hi Dijkgraff . Thanks for your support. I got the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Server` is an object that is specific to ASP Classic.

Your code is probably run by the Windows Script Host (wscript.exe / cscript.exe), which has its own `CreateObject` function.

Simply remove the `Server.` to make it work.

```vb
Set objEMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set objConfig = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

Set Confi = objConfig.Fields
Confi("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 1
Confi("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverpickupdirectory") = "C:\inetpub\mailroot\pickup"
Confi.Update

Set objEMail.Configuration = objConfig
objEMail.To = "hi@xx.in"
objEMail.From ="hello@yy.com"
objEMail.Subject = "Email subject goes here"
objEMail.HTMLBody = "Hi Sql job data"
objEMail.Send

Set objEMail = Nothing
```

For the record, the `Server` is optional in ASP Classic as well, the above code would work in both environments.